# how do I connect my java microservice docker container to a mysql server docker container using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

these are the application properties for the taskservice:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_DB_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_DB_PORT:3307}/taskdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=abc123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

server.port=8082
```

this is my Dockerfile for the taskservice:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8082
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
 mongo-notifications:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - mongodb_notification_data:/data/db
    
 mysql-user:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes:
    - mysql_user_data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
    
 mysql-task:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - 3307:3306
  volumes:
    - mysql_task_data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
    
 notification-service:
  depends_on:
    - mongo-notifications
  image: mikkyg/notificationservice:1.0
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  links:
    - mongo-notifications
  environment:
   MONGODB_PORT: 27017
   MONGODB_HOST: mongo-notifications
   
 task-service:
  depends_on:
    - mysql-task
  image: mikkyg/taskservice:1.0
  ports:
    - 8082:8082
  links:
    - mysql-task
  environment:
   MYSQL_DB_USERNAME: root
   MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: abc123
   MYSQL_DB_HOST: mysql-task
   MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3307

 user-service:
  depends_on:
    - notification-service
    - task-service
  image: mikkyg/userservice:1.0
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  links:
    - notification-service
    - task-service
  environment:
   PRODUCT_SERVICE_BASEURL: notification-service:8080
   INVENTORY_INFO_SERVICE_BASEURL: task-service:8082
   MYSQL_DB_USERNAME: root
   MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: abc123
   MYSQL_DB_HOST: mysql-user
   MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3306

volumes:
 mongodb_notification_data:
 mysql_task_data:
 mysql_user_data:
```

mikkyg/taskservice:1.0 -> this custom image is the dockerfile from the taskservice

this is one part of the logs im getting when I check the container logs of the task-service:

```
2023-11-22 18:14:37 
2023-11-22 18:14:37   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2023-11-22 18:14:37  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2023-11-22 18:14:37 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2023-11-22 18:14:37  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2023-11-22 18:14:37   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2023-11-22 18:14:37  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2023-11-22 18:14:37  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)
2023-11-22 18:14:37 
2023-11-22 18:14:38 2023-11-22T17:14:38.134Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.it.taskservice.TaskserviceApplication  : Starting TaskserviceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17-ea with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2023-11-22 18:14:38 2023-11-22T17:14:38.141Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.it.taskservice.TaskserviceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-22 18:14:40 2023-11-22T17:14:40.392Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-22 18:14:40 2023-11-22T17:14:40.776Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 352 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-22 18:14:42 2023-11-22T17:14:42.875Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2023-11-22 18:14:42 2023-11-22T17:14:42.950Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-11-22 18:14:42 2023-11-22T17:14:42.963Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.13]
2023-11-22 18:14:43 2023-11-22T17:14:43.178Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-11-22 18:14:43 2023-11-22T17:14:43.181Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4838 ms
2023-11-22 18:14:43 2023-11-22T17:14:43.662Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-22 18:14:43 2023-11-22T17:14:43.823Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.9.Final
2023-11-22 18:14:43 2023-11-22T17:14:43.832Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-11-22 18:14:44 2023-11-22T17:14:44.252Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-11-22 18:14:44 2023-11-22T17:14:44.769Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-11-22 18:14:44 2023-11-22T17:14:44.848Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-22 18:14:46 2023-11-22T17:14:46.216Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2023-11-22 18:14:46 
2023-11-22 18:14:46 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023-11-22 18:14:46 
2023-11-22 18:14:46 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-11-22 18:14:46     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
2023-11-22 18:14:46     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
```

I already checked everything from mysql-task docker container, these are its logs:

```
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22T17:14:35.845511Z 0 [System] [MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22T17:14:35.847229Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22T17:14:35.847335Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) initializing of server in progress as process 81
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22T17:14:35.890589Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-22 18:14:38 2023-11-22T17:14:38.104329Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-11-22 18:14:45 2023-11-22T17:14:45.460249Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.148979Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.393878Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.625326Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.626382Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) starting as process 125
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.644241Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22T17:15:04.871221Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.289354Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.289407Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.294768Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22 17:14:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22 17:14:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22 17:14:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
2023-11-22 18:14:35 2023-11-22 17:14:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22 17:15:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2023-11-22 18:15:04 2023-11-22 17:15:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22 17:15:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2023-11-22 18:15:05 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-11-22 18:15:08 
2023-11-22 18:15:08 2023-11-22 17:15:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22 17:15:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
2023-11-22 18:15:11 
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22 17:15:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
2023-11-22 18:15:11 
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.311028Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.311103Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-22 18:15:05 2023-11-22T17:15:05.312269Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
2023-11-22 18:15:06 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:06 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:06 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:07 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:07 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:07 Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-11-22 18:15:08 2023-11-22T17:15:08.073641Z 10 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.2.0).
2023-11-22 18:15:10 2023-11-22T17:15:10.781132Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.2.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-22 18:15:10 2023-11-22T17:15:10.790705Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22T17:15:11.086001Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22T17:15:11.351969Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22T17:15:11.354930Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) starting as process 1
2023-11-22 18:15:11 2023-11-22T17:15:11.367543Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-22 18:15:15 2023-11-22T17:15:15.729825Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-11-22 18:15:19 2023-11-22T17:15:19.891643Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-11-22 18:15:19 2023-11-22T17:15:19.892338Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-11-22 18:15:19 2023-11-22T17:15:19.981073Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-11-22 18:15:20 2023-11-22T17:15:20.013882Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-11-22 18:15:20 2023-11-22T17:15:20.014644Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For `mysql-task` service you have `3307:3306` (HOST:CONTAINER) but in `task-service` you have specified 3307. It needs to be 3306, the container (not host) port.